# Centripetal acceleration with moving (sliding) center of rotation

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, acceleration

I am working on the object-surface interaction problem. I try to figure out the equations of motion for the next system using differential equations of motion (not Lagrange).

So, the task sounds in a next way: we throw a stick on the horizontal plane, it lands on that plane with some initial velocity and angle (look at the picture).

[image: stick landing on the plane]

So, there are friction and gravity. From my simple experiment with dropping smartphone there will be a sliding and rolling simultaneously. So, I wonder, how to describe the next behavior of the stick (after landing) relatively to point A. On the one hand, the stick will slide, on another - will roll. From that point of view, it is similar to task with rolling and slipping wheel, but in my case, there is additional acceleration - centripetal (centrifugal).

And obviously, this acceleration will be around moving point (not like in the case of a cart-pendulum system, since there is a rigid connection). I solved this task for a case when it is sliding in the first moment and then rolling around fixed point, but I can't solve it for both simultaneous motions.

Thanks!

Comment: What about bouncing? If your stick makes contact with the surface, it will also rebound.

Comment: Yes, but it will be the next step.  Right now I want to consider the case without any bounces.